# how I can get a makefile to manage conditional compilation?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a C file with macros, to compile it I use gcc file.c -D and the (macro of the portion of code I want to compile).
I am writing to ask you how I can get a makefile to manage conditional compilation, in order to compile the makefile deciding whether to create the first file or the second (the two MACROs of the file c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a `Makefile` with a parameter:

```
make action argument=something
```

Then your `Makefile` can take and propagate this parameter:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS += -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall

action: $(argument)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(argument) -o demo

clean:
    rm -f demo
```

Say you have two files: `file1.c` and `file2.c`, you can call

```
make action argument=file1.c
```

or

```
make action argument=file2.c
```

to decide whether to create the first file or the second .